# How do I make two different lists with the corresponding elements of the first list?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Suppose I have a list like this:

```
[[1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 4]]
```

What I want is two different lists from the above list with first element in one list and 
the second element in the other.

The result will look like this:

```
[1,2,5] and [2,3,4]
```

Is there any way to do it by using ***list splicing*** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `zip()` to pair up the elements of the input lists:

```
lista, listb = zip(*inputlist)
```

The `*` applies the *elements* in `inputlist` as separate arguments, as if you called `zip()` as `zip([1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 4])`. `zip()` takes the first element of each argument and returns those together, and then the second element, etc.

This produces *tuples*, not lists, really, but that's easy to remedy:

```
lista, listb = map(list, zip(*inputlist))
```

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [[1, 2], [2, 3], [5, 4]]
>>> zip(*inputlist)
[(1, 2, 5), (2, 3, 4)]
>>> lista, listb = map(list, zip(*inputlist))
>>> lista
[1, 2, 5]
>>> listb
[2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: what does `*inputlist` means and how it is returning a tuple.

Comment: @Bhansa: I added an explanation for what the `*` does in a call; `zip()` returns tuples, always.

Answer (score 1):

How about use `numpy` array?

```
import numpy as np
np.array(myList).transpose()

# array([[1, 2, 5],
#        [2, 3, 4]])
```

Or

```
np.array(myList)[:, 0]
# array([1, 2, 5])

np.array(myList)[:, 1]
# array([2, 3, 4])
```